# youtube_dl: Download files synchronously via terminal

Tags: terminal, youtube-dl

I'm using the linux terminal to download files using youtube_dl.

```
youtube-dl <link>
```

However, the file is downloaded asynchronously.

Is there a simple way to have the above command block until download is complete. (The other way would have been to check for downloaded file creation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me that your URL contains ampersands, like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc&t=1s&end=9`. In a shell, the ampersand makes the program run in the background (asynchronously).

Escape ampersands in URLs, by putting the whole URL in quotes:

```
youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc&t=1s&end=9'
```

On Windows cmd, use double quotes instead:

```
youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc&t=1s&end=9"
```

Alternatively, escsape all problematic characters. Consult your shell handbook on which characters have special meanings and how to escape them. Oftentimes, a backslash will work:

```
 youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc\&t=1s\&end=9
```